# Whether the nested function hoisting affects the global variable (declared in the same function)?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```
var b = 4;
function f() {
  b = 7;
  return b;
}

a = f();
console.log(a); //output: 7
console.log(b); //output: 7
```

In the codes above, `b = 7` makes b automatically global, thus changing the value of `var b` to 7. But when a nested function b is added as below, I am confused about the output result:

```
var b = 4;
function f() {
  b = 7;
  return b;
  function b() {}
}

a = f();
console.log(a); //output: 7
console.log(b); //output: 4
```

In my opinion, since function b is hoisting in function f, a reference to function b is first created on the activation object, and when we get the interpreter gets to `b = 7`, we already see the property name b exists so the code `b = 7` does nothing and proceeds, thus `console.log(b)` outputs `4`. But how come `console.log(a)` still outputs `7`? `b = 7` should do nothing here, right?

Comment: "*we already see the property name b exists so the code `b = 7` does nothing and proceeds*" - no. It does something, namely assign to the existing local variable `b` that the function declared. In the `return` statement, that local variable is then returned. If the `b = 7` assignment did nothing, `f()` would have returned the function.

Comment: Btw, you should really forget about that "activation object" terminology. The scope is a *record*, and has an entry for the variable `b`, not a "property name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first block of code this assertion isn't accurate:

> In the codes above, b = 7 makes b automatically global, thus changing the value of var b to 7.

In the statement `b = 7`, b is bound to that outer `var b` declaration, so `b = 7` *assigns* to that `b` variable in the closure.

In the second block of code, you have a misunderstanding of what hoisting does. Think of hoisting as simply moving a declaration to the top of its scope, so:

```
function f() {
  b = 7;
  return b;
  function b() {}
}
```

...behaves as though you did this:

```
function f() {
  let b = function () { }
  b = 7;
  return b;
}
```

On the line `b = 7`, you're *assigning* a new value `7` to the local variable `b`. Hence `return b;` returns 7.